# Junit a application that reads a file and processes it

Tags: java, junit

I am working on a Java application that will read a file and then after reading it into memory will do further processing .

The requirement for file reading is that the code should read from '**current working directory**'.
I have written a method as follows:

```
public List<String> processFile(String fileName){
    String localPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").toAbsolutePath() + fileName;
}
```

This method converts the file into an ArrayList which it returns.
Then using this arraylist further processing needs to be done.

```
public boolean workOnFile(){
   List<String> records = processFile("abc.txt");
   // additional logic
}
```

I am blocked / stumped on how to Junit the file reading part since the requirement is that the file reading needs to occur from 'working directory' so wherever the user will run the program the input file would be read from working directory.

However in case of Junit my test files would be in '**\src\main\resources**'
As a result test files would not be read by the 'processFile' method since it looks for files in 'current working directory'

One thought is that I need not Junit the file reading but the entire application does something after the file is read - so do I have some 'testing' provisions where while executing Junit I read file in junit and then have provisions in my class under test to inject my testArrayList ?

```
@Test
public void doSomeValidation() {
    String testFile = "XYZ.txt";
    ClassUnderTest fixture = new ClassUnderTest();
    List<String> testList = /** read file in Junit from /src/main/resources/ **/
    /** inject this testList into ClassUnderTest **/
    fixture.setFileContent(testList );

    /** then continue testing the actual method that needs to be tested **/
    assertNotFalse(fixture.workOnFile());
}
```

To achieve this I would have to change my actual class that needs to be tested to be able to inject the test file read . Something along these lines :

```
public class ClassUnderTest(){
   public List<String> processFile(String fileName){
    String localPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").toAbsolutePath() + fileName;
   }
    /** new method used in junit to inject to **/
    public void setFileContent(List<String> input){
        this.input = input;
    }
   /** modify this method first check if injected arraylist not null **/
   public boolean workOnFile(){
      List<String> records;
      if(this.input == null){
         /** in actual runs this block will execute **/
         this.input = processFile("abc.txt");
      }
      // additional logic
   }

}
```

Is this the right way ?
I somehow feel I am messing around with code to just make it more testable ?
is this even the right approach ?

Comment: why would you do this? use a hardcoded list instead, that way you know there will never be a FileNotFound exception, or somebody who accidently changes the contents of the file, making your test crash, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution: change your interfaces to be easy to test.

Meaning:

- have one method that puts together a file name "in the local path" (the same way your `processFile()` method builds that file name
- then pass the result of that operation to your `processFile()` method.

In other words: your code **limits** that method to always compute the full path itself. Which makes it **really** hard to control, and thus to test.

Thus: dissect your problem into the smallest pieces that are possible.

Then you only need to test:

- that your new method `Path getLocalPathFor(String fileName)` does what it is supposed to do
- and then, that your method `processFile(Path absFilePath)` does what it needs to do (and now, you can test that method with a path that sits **anywhere**, not just in the local directory)

Comment: so the new method **Path getLocalPathFor(String fileName)** when does this get called - only while unit testing or in actual runs also . I still dont get how this helps since while unit testing I want the file reading to happen from **/src/main/resources/** while in actual execution file should be read from **current working directory**. Sorry have not understood your answer

Comment: @akila The point is: when you separate functionality into different methods, then testing becomes easier. You can still decide to have a method that calls both these methods. But the **main** work, of testing "lookup the local path" and "read and process *some* file" can and should be separated. So that when you also write a final method that calls both other methods, you only need a small integration test.